# retrieving and changing data of an object, which is in another object

Tags: powershell, csv, object, dynamic, reference

*passing by value or reference : powershell*

more information :
`PSVersion                      5.1.19041.906`

*All files can be found here :* [*]https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ya0Xyxewgo6FtUHVbGqSASqXOFSlXvbR?usp=sharing

I would like to try to pass an object by reference, variable. In this object I would like to pass a bunch of information (containing different other variables/data).
Sometimes there's a need to return it back (one variable), by `return $menuObjts`.

At paragraphs 'INFO' are `$menuObjts` and `$menuObjts[‘MENUS’]` shown.

More information about these object I have tried to figure it out by `gettype().fullname`.

---

**REMARK** : in the code here I've used `$global:` for allowing to ACCESS and CHANGE the variable and be able to make a screenshot and use it for test purpose.

So my problem is to ***ACCESS*** and ***CHANCE*** values in `$menuObjts[‘MENUS’]`, which is a part, element of `$menuObjts`.

Thanks to @Santiago Squarzon for his patience and quick reaction.
The idea is to create dynamically menus from the CSV file (what works) and calls the selected functions by name - `$menus_.FUNCTION` which are retrieved.
But now I would like to extend it and be able to create multi sub menus.

There are two seperate  MENU_GRP elements :

- `$menuObjts.MENU_GRP`
  -- contains info about the current/active/selected one
- `($menuObjts.**MENUS** | Where-Object {[int]**$($_).MENU_GRP** -eq  ...`
  -- `$menuObjts.MENUS` : contains all posible menus (CSV)

---

[image: CSV file - data]

So I import a range menu-items by a CSV file.
So these `$menus_` are added to `$menuObjts.MENUS` / `$menuObjts[‘MENUS’]`
There are other features in `$menus_` such as `MENU`, `PARENT`, `MENU_GRP`, `MENU_IDX`, `MENU_OFFSET`, `MENU_SEL_TYPE`, `nrElems`, `FUNCTION`, `info`, `status` , `SEL`, `RESTART`, `STOP`

```
$global:menus_ = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," $($curPath)
$menuGRP_ = 0      # 0 - MAIN
$menus_.MENU
$nrRestarts = @($menus_ | Where-Object { [int]$_.RESTART -eq 1 -and [int]$_.MENU_GRP -eq 0 }).Count
write-host (" info     : - nrRestarts: {0}" -f ($nrRestarts))
# SET : values in one object : $menuObjts
$global:menuObjts =[ordered]@{
    MENUS         = $menus_;
    MENU_GRP      = $menuGRP_;
    MENU_SEL_TYPE = $null;
    MENU_OFFSET   = $null;
    nrElems       = $null;
    sel_input     = $null;
    MENU_IDX      = $null}
```

- `$menuObjts.MENUS?MENU_GRP    =  0`  or `$menuObjts.MENUS?MENU_GRP    =  6`
- `$menuObjts.MENUS?MENU_OFFSET = -1`  or `$menuObjts.MENUS?MENU_OFFSET = 12`
- `$menuObjts.MENUS?nrElems     = 13`  or `$menuObjts.MENUS?nrElems     =  4`

`$menuObjts.MENUS ?`  - `?` because I don't know how to retrieve the underlying object and their features/data

So my problem is how to retrieve each element of `$menus_` in `$menuObjts.MENUS` again.
The idea is that via one variable, the next one will be calculated ([*]see function `updateMenuObjtsInfo` )

So my question is how can I see by type, how to get the wanted data ...

- information of variables/object `Get-Variable`

[image: get information of the variables]

- `gettype()`

`$menuObjts`
[image]

`$menuObjts.MENUS`
[image]

`$menuObjts.MENUS | select -first 1`
[image]

These are a few things I want to achieve, but this doesn't work proper `($_).MENU_GRP`

```
  $1stElementGrp_         = $($menus_ | Where { [int]$($_).MENU_GRP -eq $menuObjts.MENU_GRP }| Select -First 1 )
  $menuOFFSET_            = $($1stElementGrp_).MENU_OFFSET
  $menuNrElems_           = $($1stElementGrp_).nrElems
  #####                                         where $($menuObjts.MENUS).MENU_GRP -eq $menuObjts.MENU_GRP  -> .MENU_OFFSET
  $menuObjts.MENU_OFFSET = $($menuObjts.MENUS | Where-Object { [int]$($_).MENU_GRP -eq $menuObjts.MENU_GRP}| Select -First 1 ).MENU_OFFSET
  $menuObjts.nrElems     = @($menuObjts.MENUS | Where-Object { [int]$($_).MENU_GRP -eq $menuObjts.MENU_GRP -and [int]$($_).SEL -eq 1}).Count
```

---

Another idea … was adding methods, but I’m struggling with my (little) knowledge of Powershell.
(based on [4 Ways to Create PowerShell Objects | RidiCurious.com](https://ridicurious.com/2018/10/15/4-ways-to-create-powershell-objects) )

```
$menuObjts | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "getMENUS_RESTART" -Value $( this.MENUS | Where-Object { [int]$_.RESTART -eq 1 -and [int]$_.MENU_GRP -eq $menuGRP_ })
```

---

INFO - `$menuObjts` :

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
MENUS                          {@{MENU;PARENT;MENU_GRP;MENU_IDX;MENU_OFFSET;MENU_SEL_TYPE;nrElems;FUNCTION;info;status;SEL;RESTART;STOP=typeInstallation;LICENSE;0;0;-1;0;13;f1;Windows-Defende...
MENU_GRP                       0
MENU_SEL_TYPE
MENU_OFFSET
nrElems
sel_input
MENU_IDX
```

INFO - `$menuObjts.MENUS` :

```
MENU;PARENT;MENU_GRP;MENU_IDX;MENU_OFFSET;MENU_SEL_TYPE;nrElems;FUNCTION;info;status;SEL;RESTART;STOP
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typeInstallation;LICENSE;0;0;-1;0;13;f1;Windows-Defender has to be uninstalled                       
activate;;0;1;-1;0;13;f2;Windows has to be upgraded if working with an EVALUATION prod key;-1;0;0;0  
NAME;HOST;0;2;-1;0;13;f3;F-SEC has to be configured as an isolated machine on the CSI server;-1;0;0;0
IP;;0;3;-1;0;13;f4;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;1;0                                      
routes;;0;4;-1;0;13;f5;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;0;0                                  
users;;0;5;-1;0;13;f6;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;0;0                                   
ANTI VIRUS;SERVICEs;0;6;-1;0;13;f7;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;0;0                      
NTP;;0;7;-1;0;13;f8;;-1;0;0;0                                                                        
MEINBERG;;0;8;-1;0;13;f9;;-1;0;0;0                                                                   
addPATH;postgres;0;9;-1;0;13;f10;;-1;0;0;0                                                           
check;after CSI;0;10;-1;0;13;f11;;-1;0;0;0                                                           
execute;;0;11;-1;0;13;f12;;-1;0;0;1                                                                  
quite;;0;12;-1;0;13;f13;;-1;0;0;1                                                                    
WINDOWS DEFENDER;ANTI VIRUS;6;13;12;1;4;f14;;-1;0;0;0                                                
F-SEC;;6;14;12;1;4;f15;;-1;0;0;0                                                                     
execute;;6;15;12;1;4;f16;;-1;0;0;1                                                                   
quite;;6;16;12;1;4;f17;;-1;0;0;1
```

---

---

**Additional information [2021/05/04]**

---

---

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $menuObjts.MENUS | Get-Member
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name          MemberType   Definition
----          ----------   ----------
Equals        Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode   Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType       Method       type GetType()
ToString      Method       string ToString()
FUNCTION      NoteProperty string FUNCTION=f1
info          NoteProperty string info=Windows-Defender has to be uninstalled, before installing an other anti-virus program
MENU          NoteProperty string MENU=typeInstallation
MENU_GRP      NoteProperty string MENU_GRP=0
MENU_IDX      NoteProperty string MENU_IDX=0
MENU_OFFSET   NoteProperty string MENU_OFFSET=-1
...

PS C:\Users\Administrator> $menuObjts.MENUS 
MENU          : typeInstallation
PARENT        : LICENSE
MENU_GRP      : 0
MENU_IDX      : 0
MENU_OFFSET   : -1
MENU_SEL-TYPE :
nrElems       : 13
FUNCTION      : f1
info          : Windows-Defender has ...
status        : -1
SEL           : 0
RESTART       : 1
STOP          : 

MENU          : activate
PARENT        : 
MENU_GRP      : 0
...
```

I have the impression that `$menus_` is added as a 'value' instead as an object to `$menuObjts` - **`Value           : {@{MENU=`**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $menuObjts.MENUS.PSobject.Properties
ReferencedMemberName : Length
ConversionType       : 
MemberType           : AliasProperty
TypeNameOfValue      : System.Int32
IsSettable           : False
IsGettable           : True
Value                : 17
Name                 : Count
IsInstance           : False

MemberType      : Property
Value           : 17
IsSettable      : False
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : System.Int32
Name            : Length
IsInstance      : True
...
MemberType      : Property
Value           : {@{MENU=typeInstallation; PARENT=LICENSE; MENU_GRP=0; MENU_IDX=0; MENU_OFFSET=-1; MENU_SEL-TYPE=; nrElems=13;FUNCTION=f1; info=Windows-Defender has to be uninstalled, before installing an other anti-virus program;status=-1; SEL=0; RESTART=1; STOP=},
@{MENU=activate; PARENT=; MENU_GRP=0; MENU_IDX=1; MENU_OFFSET=-1; MENU_SEL-TYPE=; nrElems=13; FUNCTION=f2; info=Windows has to be upgraded if working with an EVALUATION prod key;status=-1; SEL=0; RESTART=0; STOP=},
@{MENU=NAME; PARENT=HOST; MENU_GRP=0; MENU_IDX=2; MENU_OFFSET=-1;MENU_SEL-TYPE=; nrElems=13; FUNCTION=f3; info=F-SEC has to be configured as an isolated machine on the CSI server;status=-1; SEL=0; RESTART=0; STOP=},
@{MENU=IP; PARENT=; MENU_GRP=0; MENU_IDX=3; MENU_OFFSET=-1; MENU_SEL-TYPE=;nrElems=13; FUNCTION=f4; info=disable default Windows NTP service; status=-1; SEL=0; RESTART=1; STOP=}...}
IsSettable      : False
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : System.Object
Name            : SyncRoot
IsInstance      : True
...
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are having trouble "filtering" your CSV in PowerShell, is that right?

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon, indeed I would like retrieve, by filtering  and math the correct item of the CSV file, which is already in the general object.
When `$menuObjts.MENU_GRP = 6` by the filter :
`$menuObjts.MENU_OFFSET = $($menuObjts.MENUS | Where-Object { [int]$($_).MENU_GRP -eq $menuObjts.MENU_GRP}| Select -First 1 ).MENU_OFFSET`
should return `12`

Comment: It's hard for me to tell what you're trying to accomplish, what I can tell you is if the CSV is delimited by `;` instead of `,` you should use `Import-Csv -Delimiter ";"` so that your `$menuObjts` object has the same properties as `Headers` of your CSV which makes it easier to manipulate.

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon, on the screenshots, you see that the CSV-data is already loaded. Indeed in powershell the arrays/hashtable ... uses the semicolumn - `;` to seperate them.
The CSV file uses  the comma - `,`.

Answer (score 3):

**First of all, I would recommend a good read on: [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1), [`about_Arrays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1) and this good article on [PS Objects](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-objects/)**

```
# Storing the CSV in the $csv var

$csv = @'
MENU;PARENT;MENU_GRP;MENU_IDX;MENU_OFFSET;MENU_SEL_TYPE;nrElems;FUNCTION;info;status;SEL;RESTART;STOP
typeInstallation;LICENSE;0;0;-1;0;13;f1;Windows-Defender has to be uninstalled                       
activate;;0;1;-1;0;13;f2;Windows has to be upgraded if working with an EVALUATION prod key;-1;0;0;0  
NAME;HOST;0;2;-1;0;13;f3;F-SEC has to be configured as an isolated machine on the CSI server;-1;0;0;0
IP;;0;3;-1;0;13;f4;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;1;0                                      
routes;;0;4;-1;0;13;f5;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;0;0                                  
users;;0;5;-1;0;13;f6;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;0;0                                   
ANTI VIRUS;SERVICEs;0;6;-1;0;13;f7;disable default Windows NTP service;-1;0;0;0                      
NTP;;0;7;-1;0;13;f8;;-1;0;0;0                                                                        
MEINBERG;;0;8;-1;0;13;f9;;-1;0;0;0                                                                   
addPATH;postgres;0;9;-1;0;13;f10;;-1;0;0;0                                                           
check;after CSI;0;10;-1;0;13;f11;;-1;0;0;0                                                           
execute;;0;11;-1;0;13;f12;;-1;0;0;1                                                                  
quite;;0;12;-1;0;13;f13;;-1;0;0;1                                                                    
WINDOWS DEFENDER;ANTI VIRUS;6;13;12;1;4;f14;;-1;0;0;0                                                
F-SEC;;6;14;12;1;4;f15;;-1;0;0;0                                                                     
execute;;6;15;12;1;4;f16;;-1;0;0;1                                                                   
quite;;6;16;12;1;4;f17;;-1;0;0;1
'@|convertfrom-csv -Delimiter ';'
```

**Get the first element of the `array`**

```
$1stElementGrp_ = $csv[0]                  # Like this
$1stElementGrp_ = $csv | Select-Object -First 1   # Or Like this
```

**Get the value of the property `MENU_OFFSET` and `nrElems` of the variable `$1stElementGrp_`**

```
$menuOFFSET_ = $1stElementGrp_.MENU_OFFSET # $menuOFFSET_ returns -1
$menuNrElems_ = $1stElementGrp_.nrElems # $menuNrElems_ returns 13
```

**Not sure what you're trying filter here**

```
# $menuObjts.MENU_OFFSET = ($menuObjts.MENUS | Where-Object {
#   [int]$($_).MENU_GRP -eq $menuObjts.MENU_GRP
# }| Select -First 1).MENU_OFFSET
# 
# $menuObjts.nrElems = @($menuObjts.MENUS | Where-Object {
#   [int]$($_).MENU_GRP -eq $menuObjts.MENU_GRP -and [int]$($_).SEL -eq 1}).Count
# }
```

**Example: If you want to filter all the rows where `MENU_OFFSET = -1`**

```
$csv | Where-Object {$_.MENU_OFFSET -eq -1} |
       Select-Object MENU, PARENT, MENU_GRP, MENU_IDX, MENU_OFFSET |
       Format-Table
```

**Returns**

```
MENU             PARENT    MENU_GRP MENU_IDX MENU_OFFSET
----             ------    -------- -------- -----------
typeInstallation LICENSE   0        0        -1
activate                   0        1        -1
NAME             HOST      0        2        -1
IP                         0        3        -1
routes                     0        4        -1
users                      0        5        -1
ANTI VIRUS       SERVICEs  0        6        -1
NTP                        0        7        -1
MEINBERG                   0        8        -1
addPATH          postgres  0        9        -1
check            after CSI 0        10       -1
execute                    0        11       -1
quite                      0        12       -1
```

Example: If you want to filter all the rows where **MENU_GRP = 6 AND MENU matches the word 'WINDOWS'**

```
$csv | Where-Object {$_.MENU_GRP -eq 6 -and $_.MENU -match 'Windows'} |
       Select-Object MENU, PARENT, MENU_GRP, MENU_IDX, MENU_OFFSET |
       Format-Table
```

**Returns:**

```
MENU             PARENT     MENU_GRP MENU_IDX MENU_OFFSET
----             ------     -------- -------- -----------
WINDOWS DEFENDER ANTI VIRUS 6        13       12
```

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is to start from the passed object `$menuObjts` containing :
(see my post - for a proper format)
`Name                           Value
----                           -----
MENUS                          {@{MENU;PARENT;MENU_GRP;MENU_IDX;MENU_OFFSET;MENU_SEL_TYPE;nrElems;FUNCTION;info;status;SEL;RESTART;STOP=typeInstallation;LICENSE;0;0;-1;0;13;f1;Windows-Defende...
MENU_GRP                       0
MENU_SEL_TYPE
MENU_OFFSET
nrElems
sel_input
MENU_IDX `

in my case `$menus` vs yours `$csv`
`$global:menuObjts =[ordered]@{
    MENUS         = $menus_; 
...`

Comment: @kris I'm sorry but I'm having a really hard time trying to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: My apologies, for my unclear explanation. I added a *remark*  in my post, to make it hopefully more clear what my problem is. Thanks for the explanations and links.
To be honest ... I thought also to retrieve it the other way around like `$menus_`.
INIT into: `$menuObjts` -
`$global:menuObjts =[ordered]@{
    MENUS = $menus_; ` so RETRIEVE `$menus_ = $menuObjts.MENUS`

Comment: I just added more information about `get-member`